# HTTPClient: Shutdown connection

Tags: java, spring, httpclient

We are having the following error (http-outgoing: Shutdown connection) within a lot of calls, most of them succesful, to the same route. There is no pool contention from the client side. It is pretty clear that connect timeout is happening. We have configured connect time out to 2 minutes.

Java/1.8.0_111
httpClient version 4.5.7

Any guess please? We would like to figure out if it is something related to local context, network context, or target context.

Application StackTrace

```
    2022-02-14 19:22:12,111 [1;31mERROR[0;39m [36m[h.bar.handlers.bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler general-scheduler-1][0;39m I/O error on GET request for "https://foo.bar.net/api/titles": Connect to foo.bar.net:443 [foo.bar.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed: connect timed out; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to foo.bar.net:443 [foo.bar.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed: connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:348)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to foo.bar.net:443 [foo.bar.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed: connect timed out
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.client.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:92)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735)
    ... 65 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://foo.bar.net/api/titles": Connect to foo.bar.net:443 [foo.bar.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed: connect timed out; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to foo.bar.net:443 [foo.bar.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] failed: connect timed out
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:354)
    at com.turner.tracker.esb.services.bar.api.titles.TitlesRepository.findByAttrs(TitlesRepository.java:69)
    at com.turner.tracker.esb.services.bar.api.titles.TitlesRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1cf229fe.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.turner.tracker.esb.services.bar.api.titles.TitlesRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$20fe8845.findByAttrs(<generated>)
    at com.turner.tracker.esb.services.bar.service.TitleService.findByExternalId(TitleService.java:88)
    at com.turner.tracker.esb.flows.aleph.bar.handlers.bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.getbarTitle(bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.java:865)
    at com.turner.tracker.esb.flows.aleph.bar.handlers.bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.lambda$decorateWithbarData$44(bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.java:800)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at com.turner.tracker.esb.flows.aleph.bar.handlers.bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.decorateWithbarData(bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.java:799)
    at com.turner.tracker.esb.flows.aleph.bar.handlers.bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.importDataIntobar(bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.java:510)
    at com.turner.tracker.esb.flows.aleph.bar.handlers.bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.processMessage(bar_RightsChangedEvent_MessageHandler.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:617)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:490)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:313)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:431)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:284)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:265)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:223)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:143)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:390)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:329)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:274)
```

HttpCLient Debug

```
170317: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,279 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies            general-scheduler-1][0;39m CookieSpec selected: default
170318: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,279 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache             general-scheduler-1][0;39m Auth cache not set in the context
170319: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,279 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager general-scheduler-1][0;39m Connection request: [route: {s}->https://foo.bar.net:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 16 of 75; total allocated: 16 of 75]
170320: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,279 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager general-scheduler-1][0;39m Connection leased: [id: 395859][route: {s}->https://foo.bar.net:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 17 of 75; total allocated: 17 of 75]
170321: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,279 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec                general-scheduler-1][0;39m Opening connection {s}->https://foo.bar.net:443
170322: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,279 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[rg.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator general-scheduler-1][0;39m Connecting to foo.bar.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
170323: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,279 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m Connecting socket to foo.bar.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 with timeout 120000
170668: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,532 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
170669: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,532 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
170670: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,532 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m Starting handshake
171114: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m Secure session established
171115: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
171116: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
171117: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m  peer principal: CN=*.bar.net
171118: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m  peer alternative names: [*.bar.net, bar.net]
171119: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m  issuer principal: CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA, O=Sectigo Limited, L=Salford, ST=Greater Manchester, C=GB
171120: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[rg.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator general-scheduler-1][0;39m Connection established xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:41070<->xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
171121: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859: set socket timeout to 120000
171122: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec                general-scheduler-1][0;39m Executing request GET /api/titles?external_id=SA_THTMND0309 HTTP/1.1
171123: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec                general-scheduler-1][0;39m Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
171124: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec                general-scheduler-1][0;39m Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
171125: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> GET /api/titles?external_id=SA_THTMND0309 HTTP/1.1
171126: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> Accept: application/xml
171127: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> Host: foo.bar.net
171128: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
171129: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.7 (Java/1.8.0_111)
171130: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
171131: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> "GET /api/titles?external_id=SA_THTMND0309 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
171132: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> "Accept: application/xml[\r][\n]"
171133: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> "Host: foo.bar.net[\r][\n]"
171134: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
171135: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.7 (Java/1.8.0_111)[\r][\n]"
171136: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
171137: 2022-02-14 19:20:11,785 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 >> "[\r][\n]"
171439: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
171440: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "Date: Mon, 14 Feb 2022 19:20:11 GMT[\r][\n]"
171441: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
171442: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
171443: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Production foo", qop="auth", algorithm=MD5, nonce="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==", opaque="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"[\r][\n]"
171444: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "X-Request-Id: 203B3699BECB_0A001EB001BB_620AAB6B_C0F1FFF03A2[\r][\n]"
171445: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "X-Runtime: 0.001511[\r][\n]"
171446: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
171447: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
171448: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "Status: 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
171449: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "Content-Length: 28[\r][\n]"
171450: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
171451: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
171452: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "[\r][\n]"
171453: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.wire                                         general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << "HTTP Digest: Access denied.[\n]"
171454: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
171455: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << Date: Mon, 14 Feb 2022 19:20:11 GMT
171456: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << Cache-Control: no-cache
171457: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
171458: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Production foo", qop="auth", algorithm=MD5, nonce="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==", opaque="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
171459: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << X-Request-Id: 203B3699BECB_0A001EB001BB_620AAB6B_C0F1FFF03A2
171460: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << X-Runtime: 0.001511
171461: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
171462: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
171463: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << Status: 401 Unauthorized
171464: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << Content-Length: 28
171465: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
171466: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.headers                                      general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
171467: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator                  general-scheduler-1][0;39m Authentication required
171468: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator                  general-scheduler-1][0;39m foo.bar.net:443 requested authentication
171469: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy     general-scheduler-1][0;39m Authentication schemes in the order of preference: [Negotiate, Kerberos, NTLM, CredSSP, Digest, Basic]
171470: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy     general-scheduler-1][0;39m Challenge for Negotiate authentication scheme not available
171471: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy     general-scheduler-1][0;39m Challenge for Kerberos authentication scheme not available
171472: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy     general-scheduler-1][0;39m Challenge for NTLM authentication scheme not available
171473: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy     general-scheduler-1][0;39m Challenge for CredSSP authentication scheme not available
171474: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.client.TargetAuthenticationStrategy     general-scheduler-1][0;39m Challenge for Basic authentication scheme not available
171475: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator                  general-scheduler-1][0;39m Selected authentication options: [DIGEST [complete=true, nonce=null, nc=0]]
171476: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,047 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859: Close connection
171477: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,048 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec                general-scheduler-1][0;39m Opening connection {s}->https://foo.bar.net:443
171478: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,048 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[rg.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator general-scheduler-1][0;39m Connecting to foo.bar.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
171479: 2022-02-14 19:20:12,048 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory          general-scheduler-1][0;39m Connecting socket to foo.bar.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 with timeout 120000
132420: 2022-02-14 19:22:12,106 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection general-scheduler-1][0;39m http-outgoing-395859: Shutdown connection
132421: 2022-02-14 19:22:12,107 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec                general-scheduler-1][0;39m Connection discarded
132422: 2022-02-14 19:22:12,107 [39mDEBUG[0;39m [36m[org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager general-scheduler-1][0;39m Connection released: [id: 395859][route: {s}->https://foo.bar.net:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 24 of 75; total allocated: 24 of 75]
```